# how to save data in the db django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, beautifulsoup

Good day, I can't really understand what I'm doing wrong in here. I was using this function base view to store my scrap data in the database with the django model, but now it's not saving any more. I can't really understand why. Any idea?

```
def weather_fetch(request):
    context = None
    corrected_rainChance = None
    url = 'http://weather.news24.com/sa/cape-town'
    extracted_city = url.split('/')[-1]
    city = extracted_city.replace('-', " ")
    print(city)
    url_request = urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url_request.read(), 'html.parser')
    city_list = soup.find(id="ctl00_WeatherContentHolder_ddlCity")
    city_as_on_website = city_list.find(text=re.compile(city, re.I)).parent
    cityId = city_as_on_website['value']
    json_url = "http://weather.news24.com/ajaxpro/TwentyFour.Weather.Web.Ajax,App_Code.ashx"

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8',
        'Host': 'weather.news24.com',
        'Origin': 'http://weather.news24.com',
        'Referer': url,
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/48.0.2564.82 Chrome/48.0.2564.82 Safari/537.36',
        'X-AjaxPro-Method': 'GetCurrentOne'}

    payload = {
        "cityId": cityId
    }
    request_post = requests.post(json_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(payload))
    data = re.sub(r"new Date\(Date\.UTC\((\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+),(\d+)\)\)", convert_date, request_post.text)
    data = data.strip(";/*")
    data = json.loads(data)
    forecast = data['Forecast']
    if forecast["Rainfall"] == '*':
        rainChance = 0
        corrected_rainChance = rainChance
    else:
        try:
            obj = WeatherData.objects.get_or_create(
                min_temp=forecast["LowTemp"], high_temp=forecast["HighTemp"],
                date=forecast["Date"], wind_speed=forecast["WindSpeed"], rain=corrected_rainChance
            )
        except WeatherData.DoesNotExist:
            obj = WeatherData.objects.get_or_create(
                min_temp=forecast["LowTemp"], high_temp=forecast["HighTemp"],
                date=forecast["Date"], wind_speed=forecast["WindSpeed"],
                rain=corrected_rainChance
            )
            obj.save()
            context = {'context': obj}
            print(context)
    return render(request, 'forecastApp/pages/fetch_weather.html', context)

class WeatherData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    wind_speed = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    high_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    min_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    rain = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(str([self.date.month, self.date.day, self.date.year]))
```

Comment: What did you change exactly?  What do you mean by "it's not saving" - do you get an error or you just can't find the object in the db?

Comment: Also, can you post your `WeatherData` class definition?

Comment: @ben432rew all I can say is I can't see anything in my db, and when I print the context it's none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely a problem with your `try/except` block. Amusing your code works until the object creation, you should change that part to:

```
if forecast["Rainfall"] == '*':
    rainChance = 0
    corrected_rainChance = rainChance
else:
    obj = WeatherData.objects.get_or_create(
            min_temp=forecast["LowTemp"], high_temp=forecast["HighTemp"],
            date=forecast["Date"], wind_speed=forecast["WindSpeed"], rain=corrected_rainChance
        )
    # obj.save()  --> you don't need to save the obj again.
    context = {'context': obj}
    print(context)
```

Comment: That's the problem this approached didn't work either. it does not save

Comment: What is the output of `context` in this case?

Comment: nothing it's not even printing that. but I have it save now by doing this   rainChance = 0
    corrected_rainChance = rainChance
    obj = WeatherData.objects.get_or_create(
        min_temp=forecast["LowTemp"], high_temp=forecast["HighTemp"],
        date=forecast["Date"], wind_speed=forecast["WindSpeed"], rain=corrected_rainChance
    )
    context = {'context': obj}
    return render(request, 'forecastApp/pages/fetch_weather.html', context)

Comment: Well, if it is not printed in this case the `else` block is not evaluated. 
So `forecast["Rainfall"] == '*'` is `True`

Comment: no I just removed the else part, for now it's not null, but there might be times when it's gonna be null

Answer (score 0):

I would say you first should clean your code. It's not looking modular at all really. You should divide the endpoint view into a modular functions, so that it will become much easier to read. You're mixing the camelCase and under_score style in your variable naming, which is regarded as bad style.

After you have done this, you are ready to move on to the actual problem :). For that, I want you to get familiar with [The python debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). With that you can easily debug python code. Oldschool way would be to insert prints in your code, but that is usually slow, unless you smell where the problem could be.

Comment: I don't know if it's really different but I use django-debug-toolbar for debugging