# how can this view be correctly saved in the model

Tags: python, django, django-views

Good day I'm trying to save this in my models, but it's not working.

```
def my_view(request)
   data = data['my_data']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_a = request.POST.get(data["data_a"])
        high_temp = request.POST.get(data["data_b"])
        date = request.POST.get(data["data_c"])
        wind_speed = request.POST.get(data["data_d"])
        obj = WeatherData.objects.create(
            data_a=data_a, data_b=data_b,
            data_c=data_c, data_d=data_d,)
        obj.save()

    return render(request, 'data.html', obj)
```

Comment: What is not working? And what is in `data['my_data']`?

Comment: What does not working mean? errors? invalid results?

Comment: @Sayse  what I meant is, it's not saving in the models, and with no error at all. But if I save in the admin site, then it's saving.

Comment: @ilse2005 has some api scrapped data. This is the original post

Comment: Is the request method `POST`? There really isn't much to go on here... (btw, `obj.save()` is pointless since create saves anyway)

Comment: do you mind checking this? this is the original post, but couldn't get help with it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708570/how-to-save-data-in-the-db-django-model/35709328#35709328 that's why I tried this approach

Comment: If you already posted the question, this should be closed as duplicate

Comment: If you're not getting any errors, then this view is simply not being called at all. The *first line* of this function should raise NameError, because you have not defined `data` anywhere. So I guess that you have some kind of URL routing problem, and your request is not going where you think it is.

Comment: I didn't get helped out of it

Comment: the view is being called, because I can view all the values in the data, but only I struggled to save them in the db.

Comment: What do you mean, "I can view all the values in the data"? Where are you viewing that? And what does "struggled to save them" mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I used the print() to display different values in the terminal. My issue is those data's are not being saved. I tried may ways but no luck so far. This is how it's actually in my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708570/how-to-save-data-in-the-db-django-model/35709328#35709328, this one posted in here was my latest attempt to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ModelForm: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform

```
forms.py:
class WeatherForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Weather
         fields = ['data_a', 'data_b', 'data_c', 'data_d']
views:
def my_view(request)
   data = data['my_data']
   form = WeatherForm(request.POST or None)
   if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
   else: 
       obj = None
   return render(request, 'data.html', {'form': form, 'obj': obj})
```

Comment: do you mind checking this? this is the original post, but couldn't get help with it stackoverflow.com/questions/35708570/… that's why I tried this approach

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have parameters in `POST` your code should look like this:

```
def my_view(request)
    data = data['my_data']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        data_a = request.POST.get(data["data_a"])
        data_b = request.POST.get(data["data_b"])
        data_c = request.POST.get(data["data_c"])
        data_d = request.POST.get(data["data_d"])
        obj = WeatherData.objects.create(
            data_a=data_a, data_b=data_b,
            data_c=data_c, data_d=data_d,)
        # obj.save() --> you don't need save because you already called `create`

    return render(request, 'data.html', obj)
```

Comment: do you mind checking this? this is the original post, but couldn't get help with it stackoverflow.com/questions/35708570/… that's why I tried this approach

Comment: @DaveBecks , if the answer helped you, please accept it.